# Controller not seeing the updated model - asynchronous handling

Tags: ember.js

I have a very simple requirement but like with many things in Ember.JS, I'm banging my head against the wall trying to get it implemented.

I have an overview screen where a couple of records are displayed in a table.

To render the overview screen I'm using the following Route

```
App.LocationsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  setupController: function(controller) {
    var locations = App.Location.find();
    controller.set('content', locations);
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('locations.index',{into:'application'});
  }

});
```

This is working fine.
I would now like to conditionally render the overviewtable.

- If records are present render the table.
- If no records are present display a message.

I tried implementing this using the following controller.

```
App.LocationsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  locationsPresent: function() {
    var model = this.get('content');
    return model.content.length > 0;
  }.property()
});
```

and the following template

```
{{#if locationsPresent}}

  <table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Latitude</th>
    <th>Longitude</th>
    <th>Accuracy</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
    {{#each location in model}}
      <tr>
      <td>{{location.latitude}}</td>
      <td>{{location.longitude}}</td>
      <td>{{location.accuracy}}</td>
      <td>{{#linkTo locations.edit location}}Edit{{/linkTo}}</td>
      <td><button {{action removeItem location}}>Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>

{{else}}
  No locations present.
{{/if}}
```

The computed `locationsPresent` property is called once, before the page is rendered. At that time I assume that the model is still being loaded as the length = 0.

When the page is rendered, the locations from the App.Locations.find() are available but the locationsPresent is not called anymore, meaning the page decided to render the `No locations present.` message.

I went through the [Managing Asyncrony in Ember](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/managing-asynchrony/) page and assumed that the computer property `locationsPresent` would be updated if the underlying model changed (if it was completely loaded) as the page states :

*Using a computed property for author eliminated the need to explicitly invoke the computation in a callback when the underlying property changed.*

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this but more importantly why I seem to be missing some of these core concepts of Ember.JS. If somebody can point me where in the docs / guides this is explained properly I'd love to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a easy fix. You need to add the property you are observing. like so:

```
locationsPresent: function() {
  var length = this.get('content.length');
  return length > 0;
}.property('content.@each')
```

adding the @each is necessary if locationsPresent needs to recalculate wen content is added. I think you can also observe 'content.isLoaded'

Comment: had tried property("content") but missed the '@each'. It now works fine with the '@each'. thx .... property("content.isLoaded") doesn't seem to be working.